# Graduation and privileges

Tags: support, policy

I noticed that most of the privileges for graduated sites require higher reps than for beta sites. While this makes sense to me for a number of reasons, will it then mean that upon CS.SE's eventual graduation many of us will no longer be able to do some things to which we've been accustomed?

Comment: possible graduation has been a topic for over a year. there seems to be a se site-wide backlog. not sure where this site is in the queue. very little feedback from se mgt on that. therefore maybe it wont be much of an issue for indefinite future. it also comes down to your rep, you may be over the threshhold in both cases for particular actions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes -- until you earn more rep.

Comment: Well, ain't that a pity.

Comment: @RickDecker Yea. However, from a birdseye perspective, the hurt is probably minimal. Relatively few of those who have the rep (now) use it, anyway. Those who are active are probably in a position to earn the necessary rep. If you are interested, I'm sure there are plenty of posts about this on [meta.SE]; I seem to remember one discussion about whether the raised rep requirements are actually appropriate for smaller graduated sites, and if the requirements should not scale with the site instead of being a binary thing.